# Does a django model know from which database it was loaded and how can this info be accessed?

Tags: django, django-models

So, for instance, we have this code:

```
for book in myapp.models.Book.objects.using('alternate_database').all():
    #...
    book.save()
```

Would be books saved to `'alternate_database'` or to the `'default'` one? If they would be saved to an alternate one, then models seem to be aware from which databases they are loaded from.

Where this informtion is stored? How can i get database name from a model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, here is the right answer. The database name is saved in `ModelState` class in `db` field, which is instantciated in `Model._state`

So, it goes like this for the example above:

```
for book in myapp.models.Book.objects.using('alternate_database').all():
    print book._state.db #output: 'alternate_database'
    book.save()
    print book._state.db #output: 'alternate_database'
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do:
`book.save(using='alternate_database')`

According to this:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save

Comment: Thank you, capt'n. This was not the question, sorry.