# Get database django model object was queried from

Tags: django, django-models

I have an application which uses multiple databases. Once a model instance object is in memory, how can I determine what database it came from?  Specifically I would like to know this for use in a method on the model class.

Example:

```
class book(Models.model):
    newdate = models.DateField(default=date.today())
    type = models.CharField(
                            max_length=30,
                            choices=BOOK_TYPE,
                            default = 'novel',
                            )
    def get_current_student(self):
        if not hasattr(self,'_current_student'):
            try:
                self._current_student = clickerlog.objects.using(SELF.ORIGIN_DATABASE).get(book=self.pk,end__isnull = True).student
            except:
                self._current_student = none
        return self._current_student

class booklog(Models.model):
    start = models.DateTimeField(
                                 default=datetime.now(),
                                 verbose_name = 'start time'
                                 )
    end = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True,)
    book = models.ForeignKey(book)
    student = models.ForeignKey(student,
                              limit_choices_to = {'isactive':True})
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929629/how-to-get-the-database-where-a-model-instance-was-saved-to-in-django

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does a django model know from which database it was loaded and how can this info be accessed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146781/does-a-django-model-know-from-which-database-it-was-loaded-and-how-can-this-info)

Answer (score 20):

After a litte more digging I found it:

```
self._state.db
```